# is_constructible and is_destructible unaffected by friend declarations

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, access-modifiers

Clang and GCC appear not to honor `friend` declarations when evaluating `std::is_constructible` and `std::is_destructible`.

Regarding `is_constructible, [cppreference.com says:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_constructible)

> Access checks are performed as if from a context unrelated to T and any of the types in Args. Only the validity of the immediate context of the variable definition is considered.

(The site doesn't explain how `is_destructible` deals with access checks, but access modifiers *do* affect the behavior of `is_destructible` in general, so I'd expect it to work the same way as `is_constructible`.)

Therefore, it seems to me that this code should **not** compile, since in the *immediate context* of the check the constructor and destructor *are* available, as evidenced by the local variable instantiation:

```
class Private
{
    Private() {}
    ~Private() {}

    friend class Friend;
};

class Friend
{
    public:
        Friend()
        {
            // Both of these should fire, but they do not.
            static_assert(
                !std::is_constructible<Private>::value,
                "the constructor is public");
            static_assert(
                !std::is_destructible<Private>::value,
                "the destructor is public");
            // There is no error here.
            Private p;
        }
};
```

...but [Coliru compiles it without error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54c1a1d0b19d2d86) (using either GCC or Clang).

Is this a bug (or at least a nonconformity) in *both* compilers, or is cppreference.com misrepresenting the standard, or am I misunderstanding cppreference.com's statement?

Comment: This is basically a quote straight from the standard (with a couple words changed). Also, that's not what "immediate context" means.

Comment: @T.C. I don't know what "immediate context" means in standardese, but it surprises me immensely that the result of `is_constructible` tells you nothing about whether or not the object can be constructed in the *very next line of code*.

Comment: The alternative is that the same type (`is_constructible<T, Args..>`) *has different base classes* depending on where it is used.

Comment: @T.C. Okay, I see how the version I was imagining would be impossible to implement and also somewhat nonsensical in terms of the type system. I think I understand "immediate context" a little better after reading [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15260685/1858225), but I certainly don't feel that it's an intuitively understandable phrase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is exactly what

> Access checks are performed as if from a context unrelated to `T` and
>   any of the types in `Args`.

says. "A friend of `T`" is by definition not "unrelated to `T`".

["immediate context"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15260685/1858225) is a term of art, but in any event the sentence is talking about the immediate context of the hypothetical variable definition, not the use of `is_constructible`.

It would be madness to make the `is_constructible` check context-dependent; that would mean that the same type, `is_constructible<T, Args...>`, has different base classes in different contexts.